# Changing the windows UUID volume with Debian

Tags: debian, windows, usb-drive, ntfs, uuid

I'd like to be able to put an ID on a USB key formatted in NTFS under debian and be able to read it with Windows 7 and 10.
As the identifier must be unique, I prefer to use UUID rather than label.

I tried several solutions, especially `ntfslabel --new-serial /dev/sdX` but it seems that Windows only reads the first 8 values of the UUID in hexa and `ntfslabel` doesn't change the UUID volume.

How can I change the UUID volume used by windows with Debian? Otherwise, how can I set an id in the USB stick settings with Debian and read it under Windows?

Comment: Did you consider using [VFAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT) formatted USB keys? They are readable and writable by Windows and by Linux.

Comment: Yeah, of course, but I'm forced to use NTFS

Answer (score 1):

1. generate a new UUID with `uuidgen`
2. Find out where your USB key is mounted (e.g. `/dev/sdb1, /dev/sdc1, ...`)
3. Assign the generated UUID to the volume with

   `tune2fs -U <the generated UUID> /dev/<the device address for your USB key>`

or use the `gparted` program to assign a new UUID to the USB key

---

EDIT: Sorry, didn't take notice of it being a ntfs stick. Normally ntfs file systems don't use UUID. I'll see if I can come up with something.

There is a recipe for how to do it on MacOSX on https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/229416/how-can-i-change-an-ntfs-volume-uuid but it seems both complicated and risky.

A suitable hex editor on Linux would be bless. If you try this I suggest you take a copy of your data on the USB key first.

I do mount NTFS external HDDs on my Ubuntu system and use the NTFS volume serial number as identifier, it works as well as a UUID

---

EDIT2: It seems that the NTFS (or FAT) volume serial number is used as UUID on Linux systems and that there is room for only a half of the UUID if you attempt to replace the volume serial number with a UUID. In addition, the WPA key on the NTFS file system may be rendered invalid and make the volume unusable on Windows, at least some users have reported this. (Also some users that have replaced the NTFS volume serial number with a UUID on the system partition of Windows have reported that they no longer can log in.)

---

EDIT3: Finally! If you assign a label to the file system on a USB key, it is used when mounting the USB key.

If you don't assign a label to a USB key, then if it is a NTFS formated key, the volume serial number is used in the same way as a UUID.

Comment: tune2fs doesn't work since I'm using NTFS. The problem is not to change the UUID on debian but to access the modified UUID with windows

Comment: But it is not necessary as the normal NTFS volume serial number is (almost) as unique as a UUID and used in the case that there is no label assigned to the USB key.